# Can not show image in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I can not understand why react admin refuses to show pictures

This is the code of the component

```
const RecipeShow = (props) => {
const controllerProps = useShowController(props);
return (
  <ShowContextProvider value={controllerProps}>
    <ShowView title={<RecipeTitle />} actions={<ShowActions />}>
      <SimpleShowLayout>
        <TextField source="title" addLabel={false} />

        <ArrayField source="pictures">
          <Datagrid>
            <ImageField src="url" title="name" />
            <TextField source="url" />
            <TextField source="name" />
          </Datagrid>
        </ArrayField>
```

here is how data looks like

```
recipes: [
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Cheat's cranberry sauce",
  ingredients: [
    { amount: 1, product: "eating apple" },
  ],
  pictures: [
    {
      name: "the picture name",
      url: "https://img.jamieoliver.com/jamieoliver/recipe-database/CnUjARk04FJBqc7pO-1BVO.jpg?tr=w-800,h-1066",
    },
  ],
  published_at: new Date("2012-08-06"),
```

....

and inside the html page I see only empty div, and no errors

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox?

Comment: In the browser debugger (Network tab), see if there is a download request
images and what is its result.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it!